# Response.Redirect() disables back-button

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, iis-7, post-redirect-get

As far as I understand, `Response.Redirect("http://stackoverflow.com");` tells the browser to initiate a request to another URL.

One of the results of this is that the browser "remembers" the redirection, and allows pressing "back."

However, I have a website where `Response.Redirect` disables the ability to press the browser's "Back" button, as if the browser had opened a new window. (Browsing history is not forgotten, unlike with `Server.Transfer`.)

The redirection used to work properly in the past, so I suspect the problem has something to do with the IIS server (IIS7).

I apologize in advance if this question should be moved to [ServerFault.com](http://Serverfault.com).

**UPDATES**:

1. Here is some code:

   ```
   protected void btnClickMe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       // ...
       // some server-side logic
       // ...

       Response.Redirect("NewPage.aspx?ProductID=" + idNum);
   }
   ```
2. Regarding "*disables the ability to press the browser's 'Back' button*", what I meant is that the button cannot be pressed. Same as when you open a new window. The button is gray, and clicking it has absolutely no effect.

**UPDATE 2**:

This has been tested with IE6 and IE8.

Comment: Response.Redirect does not have that effect. Could we see some code?

Comment: If U r redirecting in another site then it will create new session

Comment: Please elaborate on the part *disables the ability to press the browser's "Back" button* - what happens when you do that? You reach the previous page?

Comment: @AndrewBarber I added sample code.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I updated as requested.

Comment: @SunilChavan The page is in the same site.

Comment: Well, from your code looks like you are redirecting after a Post Back. See the accepted answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1791416/prevent-postback-when-user-clicks-browsers-back-button): *With this kind of code, the POST to the original page will not end up in the browser history*

Comment: @ShadowWizard I don't need the POST. I need the pages that came before that.

Comment: That's weird then - what are those pages? Are all on your domain, without POST of their own?

Comment: Might be worth using a http sniffer to check that response.redirect is returning a 302 redirect, if that its being returned then there's really no way it should be causing that behaviour. Can you also tell us what browsers you are testing in. 

I'm wondering if this is specific to a browser that is trying to heuristically find situations where hitting back wouldn't actually take the user back and would just cause other redirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was NOT with the `Response.Redirect();`.

When I was on OldPage.aspx, I entered a new URL in the address bar. Once the browser loaded the new site, it disabled the back-button.

Conclusion: There is something wrong with OldPage.aspx, not the redirection to NewPage.aspx.

I still don't know why THIS happens, but this is an entirely different question.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack) //check if the webpage is loaded for the first time.
        {
            ViewState["PreviousPage"] = 
        Request.UrlReferrer;//Saves the Previous page url in ViewState
        }
    }
    protected void btnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["PreviousPage"] != null)  //Check if the ViewState 
                        //contains Previous page URL
        {
            Response.Redirect(ViewState["PreviousPage"].ToString());//Redirect to 
        //Previous page by retrieving the PreviousPage Url from ViewState.
        }
    }
```